# Oracle timestamp in number format SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have my datetime column in table defined as Oracle NUMBER data type which contains data in this format 1363709957 for example.

I want to get these numbers in query so i can execute my insert scripts which will put in current time in there. What is the oracle SQL for that?

Comment: @Ben I do not want any conversion here. I just want the epoch time in oracle sql in NUMBER format.

Answer (score 2):

Your time stamp appears to be a standard Unix time stamp.  You need to use arithmetic to convert this [here's a post on OTN about this](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2304187),

[and one for the other direction](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=338574).

Comment: I am using this SELECT (SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01-01-1970 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60 * 60 FROM DUAL. But then it gives me values as 1364264318.999999999999999999999999999998 and not as whole number

Comment: This is normal floating point behavior. You can use the ROUND() function to make an integer of it.  The INTEGER() function will truncate, so you need to round.